# Effect size and power analysis for zero-inflated negative binomial mixed models

Tags: r, mixed-model, effect-size, statistical-power, zero-inflation

I'm working with a zero-inflated dataset (confirmed using `vcdExtra::zero.test`) of bat calls per unit time (i.e. bat activity), which I'm relating to the occurrence of passenger trains passing the recording site.

To assess the effect of passing trains, I compared the number of bat calls in the **30 seconds** *before*, *after* and *between* train passes using a zero-inflated negative binomial mixed model (`glmmTMB` package) with the structure:

```
glmmTMB(bat call rate ~ category + (1|site),
                        ziformula = ~.,
                        family = nbinom2)
```

...where `category` is either *before*, *after* or *between*, and `(1|site)` accounts for repeated measures at each location.

This showed the number of bat calls was lower in the *after* category (i.e. there was less activity in the **30 seconds** after a train passed).

To examine if the reduction in calls lasts longer than **30 seconds**, I re-ran the model comparing bat call rates from time intervals of increasing duration - **60**/**120**/**240 seconds** - divided into the same *before*, *after* and *between* train categories. And, `category` was no longer significant in any of these models.

All intervals between trains are ≥ 90 seconds in duration, with frequency decreasing as duration increases. This means sample size reduced sequentially from 3000 in the initial **30 second** model, to 1800 in the **60 second** model, 1000 in the **120 second** model, and 500 in the **240 second** model.

I'd like to determine whether the lack of relationship in the **60**/**120**/**240 seconds** models is because there is only a reduction in bat calls for **30 seconds**, or is due to their lower sample sizes.

I assume (perhaps naively) I could do this by comparing the effect size for the **30 seconds** model with the power of the **60**/**120**/**240 seconds** models. But, I'm not sure how to calculate these values (it's my first time using zero-inflated models).

According to [Johnson et al. (2015)](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/2041-210X.12306), it is possible, but there's no information in the paper about how to do it, and  `GLMMmisc::sim.glmm` doesn't seem to work with `glmmTMB` models.

Any advice, or ideas for alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In general, performing a power analysis for your own study is not a good idea; see [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/000313001300339897) from more info. The information you have in your own data is summarized in the corresponding confidence intervals.

If you still like to do a power analysis for a future study using the zero-inflated negative binomial model, then it is indeed the best way to do it via simulation. The following code simulates from a simple version of this model. You could adapt it to your needs:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 300 # number of subjects
K <- 8 # number of measurements per subject
t_max <- 5 # maximum follow-up time

# we constuct a data frame with the design: 
# everyone has a baseline measurment, and then measurements at random follow-up times
DF <- data.frame(id = rep(seq_len(n), each = K),
                 time = c(replicate(n, c(0, sort(runif(K - 1, 0, t_max))))),
                 sex = rep(gl(2, n/2, labels = c("male", "female")), each = K))

# design matrices for the fixed and random effects non-zero part
X <- model.matrix(~ sex * time, data = DF)
Z <- model.matrix(~ 1, data = DF)
# design matrices for the fixed and random effects zero part
X_zi <- model.matrix(~ sex, data = DF)
Z_zi <- model.matrix(~ 1, data = DF)

betas <- c(1.5, 0.05, 0.05, -0.03) # fixed effects coefficients non-zero part
shape <- 2 # shape/size parameter of the negative binomial distribution
gammas <- c(-1.5, 0.5) # fixed effects coefficients zero part
D11 <- 0.5 # variance of random intercepts non-zero part
D22 <- 0.4 # variance of random intercepts zero part

# we simulate random effects
b <- cbind(rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(D11)), rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(D22)))
# linear predictor non-zero part
eta_y <- as.vector(X %*% betas + rowSums(Z * b[DF$id, 1, drop = FALSE]))
# linear predictor zero part
eta_zi <- as.vector(X_zi %*% gammas + rowSums(Z_zi * b[DF$id, 2, drop = FALSE]))
# we simulate negative binomial longitudinal data
DF$y <- rnbinom(n * K, size = shape, mu = exp(eta_y))
# we set the extra zeros
DF$y[as.logical(rbinom(n * K, size = 1, prob = plogis(eta_zi)))] <- 0
```